# Test Setup in between data-driven style testing

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven

I have created some test cases using the data-driven style testing.

But when attaching the `Test Setup`/`Teardown` to the `Setting` section, both the setup and teardown runs before and after the testing all the data sets.

Robot

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup  setup
Test Teardown  teardown

*** Keywords ***

Test Case Should Pass
    [Arguments]  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
    something "${arg1}"
    something "${arg2}"
    something "${arg3}"

something "${arg}"
    Log To Console  ${arg}

setup
    Log To Console  setup

teardown
    Log To Console  teardown

*** Test Case ***

Test Case
    [Template]  Test Case Should Pass
    a1  a2  a3
    b1  b2  b3
```

Actual

```
==============================================================================
Something
==============================================================================
Test Case                                                             setup
.a1
a2
a3
.b1
b2
b3
.teardown
Test Case                                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Something                                                             | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Expected

```
==============================================================================
Something
==============================================================================
Test Case                                                             setup
.a1
a2
a3
teardown
setup
.b1
b2
b3
.teardown
Test Case                                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Something                                                             | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Are there any way that I can have the `Setup`/`Teardown` to be executed in between each data set tested?

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup  setup
Test Teardown  teardown
Test Template  Test Case Should Pass

*** Keywords ***

Test Case Should Pass
    [Arguments]  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
    something "${arg1}"
    something "${arg2}"
    something "${arg3}"

something "${arg}"
    Log To Console  ${arg}

setup
    Log To Console  setup

teardown
    Log To Console  teardown

*** Test Case ***
A
    a1  a2  a3
B
    b1  b2  b3
```

Comment: I have tried this approach as well. But I was hoping that it can be achieved without having to put them under different test cases.

Comment: Me too, however, it's not possible to use `[Setup]` in the template keyword, so it has to be introduced as a regular keyword as the first step of the template or do like this.